# What is the "for(;;)" syntax in this code?

Tags: php, syntax, for-loop

```
   for(;;)
   {
     if(!$monitor->Throttle($cause))
       die('Fatal error: '.$monitor->error);

     if($cause == THROTTLE_CAUSE_NONE)
       break;

     sleep(60);
   }
```

i'm a beginner php developer. So how do you read the "for" syntax in previous code. is it valid ?

i got them from http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/132-Accelerate-Page-Accesses-Throttling-Background-Tasks-Unusual-Site-Speedup-Techniques-Part-2.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`for(;;)` is a C idiom which means "do forever", an infinite loop. This loop will only exit when either the `die` statement fires (violently) , or the cause is set to `THROTTLE_CAUSE_NONE` (not so violently).

It's a `for` loop with no pre-setup, no condition and not post-iteration commands, effectively the same as `while true` (pseudo-code).

Answer (score 7):

That's a forever-loop.

Comment: @BoltCLock I'm happy at least someone recognized it.

Answer (score 4):

`for(;;)` is basically an infinite loop, nothing more :)

Answer (score 4):

Ugh.

It is valid syntax, it creates an infinite loop. But it's ugly.

A much more beautiful way to do this would be

```
 while ($cause = $monitor->Throttle($cause) != THROTTLE_CAUSE_NONE)
 {
    if(!$cause)
     die('Fatal error: '.$monitor->error);

    sleep(60);   
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is valid.  It creates an infinite loop, which in this case will be broken out of when/if the break statement executes, i.e. `if($cause == THROTTLE_CAUSE_NONE)`

Answer (score 2):

The for loop has four parts:

```
for(initialization; exit condition; step) { body; }
```

Your loop has none of them, so without an exit condition it will just run forever until it hits the 'break' sentence:

```
if($cause == THROTTLE_CAUSE_NONE)
  break;
```

An equivalent would be:

```
while(True) { ... }
```