# What does "for(;;)" mean?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, for-loop

In C/C++, what does the following mean?

```
for(;;){
    ...
}
```

Comment: The forever alone loop.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031636/what-is-the-for-syntax-in-this-code/4031654#4031654 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737550/what-does-for-mean-in-perl/2737623#2737623 - I didn't count them as dupes since they're PHP/Perl but I'd be surprised if this hadn't been asked before. However, since I can't find a C one, you're safe for now :-)

Comment: I didn't think I would be the first person to ask, but I tried searching before I asked. There's no keywords to search for, and I'll admit, I was a bit lazy.

Comment: no problem, we love these types of questions! it's a race to the answer button

Comment: I suggest for(;"ever";) { code }

Comment: also `for(;true;){/*code*/}`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's an infinite loop, equivalent to `while(true)`.  When no termination condition is provided, the condition defaults to false (i.e., the loop will not terminate).

Comment: The reason why one would write `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)` is because some compilers will issue a warning for the constant boolean expression in `while(true)`. For example, Visual C++ gives me a "warning C4127: conditional expression is constant" with `while(true)`.

Comment: But it is exactly the same in terms of functionality.

Comment: @In silico: It's also four characters shorter, if you're into the whole golfing thing.

Comment: Another reason, I believe, is some people consider it more readable.

Comment: Morgan: There's a [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490823/why-msvc-generates-warning-c4127-whan-constant-is-used-in-while-c) that pertains to `for(;;)` vs. `while(true)` with respect to the Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: The other thing that wasn't mentioned is that using while() will force the compiler to check the value each iteration, for(;;) is faster since it will not do so.

Answer (score 17):

In C and C++ (and quite a few other languages as well), the `for` loop has three sections:

- a pre-loop section, which executes before the loop starts;
- an iteration condition section which, while true, will execute the body of the loop; and
- a post-iteration section which is executed after each iteration of the loop body.

For example:

```
for (i = 1, accum = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    accum += i;
```

will add up the numbers from 1 to 10 inclusive.

It's roughly equivalent to the following:

```
i = 1;
accum = 0;
while (i <= 10) {
    accum += i;
    i++;
}
```

However, nothing requires that the sections in a `for` statement actually *contain* anything and, if the iteration condition is missing, it's assumed to be true.

So the `for(;;)` loop basically just means:

- don't do any loop setup;
- loop forever (breaks, returns and so forth notwithstanding); and
- don't do any post-iteration processing.

In other words, it's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 8):

Loop until some `break`, `exit`, `throw` etc. statement inside the loop executes.  Basically, you can think of a `for` loop as consisting of:

```
for (setup; test; advance)
    ...
```

If the "test" is empty it's considered to be `true`, and the loop keeps running.  Empty "setup" and "advance" simply do nothing.

Answer (score 6):

An infinite loop which continues until there is a `break`, `exit`, or `goto` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Even if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4894126/6451573) suggests that both constructs are equivalent, there's a subtle difference between both `for(;;)` and `while(1)` (which both create infinite loops) in the C language (and possibly compiler-dependent).

Some compilers (Windriver DIABData for instance) complain about "condition is always true" when using `while(1)`.

Changing to `for(;;)` allows to get rid of the warning, probably because the latter expression is semantically stronger to create an infinite loop on purpose, and there is no "always true" condition at all (plus it's shorter to write).

On the other hand, the C++ language doesn't make a difference about both constructs as Adrian stated in comments:

The C++ standard states that a missing condition makes the implied `while` clause equivalent to `while(true)` and `for ( for-init-statement condition opt ; expression opt )` statement is equivalent to `{ for-init-statement while ( condition ) { statement expression ; } }`

Comment: In the **C++** language standard, section `[stmt.for]` explicitly states that   _A missing condition makes the implied_ `while` _clause equivalent to_ `while(true)`  and `for ( for-init-statement condition opt ; expression opt ) statement` _is equivalent to_ `{ for-init-statement while ( condition ) { statement expression ; } }`. In sum we have `for(;;)` is equivalent to `while(true)`. Since you wrote `while(1)` this may be only holds for `C`, not `C++`?