# Why does this 'for(;;)' loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop

What in the world is making the second parameter return `true`?

> **WARNING: it will loop infinitely and might crash your browser**

```
for(;;){
    //...
}
```

I was totally expecting not to loop at all...

But it is running, and that makes it worse since it can only be running if something evaluated to `true`, or am I missing something?

Comment: If there's no condition given at all, a for loop runs until you break out of it. It's the same in C.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894120/special-for-loop-syntax/4894256#4894256 - just the same in Java and JavaScript as it is in C and C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [**`for`**<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

`[Initialization]` and `[final-expression]` are intuitively not required, reducing the construct to a simple `while` loop. But the relevant part is:

> **condition**
>   An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. **This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true.** If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.

(emphasis mine)

This appears to be a totally arbitrary JS language design decision. If it were my language I would probably throw a syntax error.

---

On a playful side note, `for(;;){}` is equivalent to `while(true){}`, and happens to be 4 characters shorter. I wonder if minifiers leverage this!

Answer (score 4):

Because the lack of a condition will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Really?  That's kind of hokey.  Is that how it works everywhere in Java?  As in `if()` ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, the syntax prevents `if()` from not having a condition, but it doesn't prevent `for()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing “making the second parameter return `true`”.  There is no second parameter.  Section 12.6.3 of the [ECMAScript Language Specification (ECMA-262 5th Edition)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) says this:

> a. If the first *Expression* is present, then
>
> i. Let *testExprRef* be the result of evaluating the first
>   *Expression*.
>
> ii. If GetValue(*testExprRef*) is **false**, return (`normal`, *V*,
>   `empty`).

The “first *Expression*” it's referring to is the optional expression between the semicolons of the `for` statement.  If it's present, the program performs steps (i) and (ii) quoted above.  If the expression is not present, the program simply doesn't perform steps (i) and (ii) of the `for` statement algorithm.