# What's the meaning of " for ( ; ; ) " in C?

Tags: c, system

I'm using C for my subject of Operative Systems and I've seen the use of `for( ;; )` and I don't know the meaning. I can guess it's an infinite loop.

```
int sfd, tfd;
char c;
for (;;) {
    if ( read (sdf , &c , 1) != 1 ) return;
    write( tfd, &c, 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed an infinite loop, requiring a `break` or `return` (or a jump) to exit it.

It's preferred over the equivalent `while(1)` as that will often issue a compiler warning whereas `for(;;)` almost certainly will not.

Comment: Are you sure about the second sentence? I think it is a purely stylistic thing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Indeed I am; because each expression in the `for` is optional, compilers don't bother to weed out odd cases, so `for(;;)` established itself as the idiom.

Comment: some compilers complain for `while(1)` where `for(;;)` silence their warnings (Windriver/Diabdata) so there's a difference.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Absolutely!

Comment: you're right for the C++ part, it's different, as a comment states below my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238756/6451573

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Nice plug. Just upvoted it!

Comment: thanks. appreciate it. now I have to edit the comment into my answer...

Answer (score 2):

The `for` statement (see [c99 6.8.5.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.8.5.3)) has 3 (optional) parts: *initialization*, *condition*, and *increment*.

The absence of the 'condition' part is interpreted as *true* (see [c99 6.8.5.3p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.8.5.3p2))

> ... An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.

Comment: I think you can post your (good) answer in the "original" question of 2011 instead of replying to obvious duplicates.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: But then pmg would have to generalise the answer to C++ where the `for` loop is a different beast, and they answerer would need to dig out a corresponding C++ standard reference.